# Girl on alien spaceship wakes up from stasis pod alone, occupants of other pods long dead; early 80s story or book

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a sci-fi story in about the 6th or 7th grade. The movie "Passengers" triggered the memory.  What I remember is that it was about a young girl waking up from a stasis "pod" or "cocoon" on a colony type ship on a super long trip.  The cocoons were held on rack in levels and layers. In trying to get to someone to speak to, the girl falls into a "dead" pod, where the occupant has long since died.  She then realizes that there are many more pods like it.  Only other thing I can remember is I think the ship was piloted by aliens and they were lost. I think we read it in class about the same time we read the Bradbury story "They Were Dark and Golden Eyed".  This was back in the EARLY 80's, so it could be even older.

Comment: For reference, *Dark They Were, and Golden-Eyed* is from 1949, though it was collected in multiple anthologies besides *The Martian Chronicles*.

Comment: Looks like "Across the Universe" by Beth Revis https://www.jengambale.com/2016/06/16/across-the-universe-by-beth-revis/, but it is from 2011